# Type to store a highly precise decimal < 1

Tags: c++

I have a number less than one that I need to store. For example, the number would look like this:

```
0.002937595900
```

I need to keep all levels of precision (let's say up to a max of 12). What would be the most efficient way to store this in cpp? I was hoping something smaller than using something like the [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/high_precision/use_multiprecision.html) model/decimal type could be used.

Would there be another way I could store it?

The application I'm trying to support is to store a time of up to microsecond precision, where the number 1 represents "1 day", which using Google looks like there are 8.64e+10 microseconds in a day, so about 1 / 8.64e+10 in precision.

Comment: does the regular `double` not work for you? How much more precise does it need to be?

Comment: @Chipster -- I'm not sure, to be honest. I just need to ensure that it is accurate up to 12 decimal places and can never have a rounding error (for example, like a float).

Comment: see http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/86683/

Comment: Also, this: [doubles have 15 digits of precision](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-float-double-c-cpp/).

Comment: @Chipster got it, so basically it would only be if I have more than 15 digits that I'd need to use one of the arbitrary-precision libraries. Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be that way.

Comment: Your question does not have enough information in it. You're not asking the real question. You sort of think you have an answer to the question and are trying to work out the details. You should probably ask your real question.

Comment: @Omnifarious thanks for this suggestion, I've added a bit more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on exactly what kind of precision you need. If you need to make sure the number stays within about 1 / 2^52 the value you want, a `double` is your best bet. If you need an exact number of digits of precision when the number is represented in decimal, the boost class you mention might be your best bet.

Given your application, I would store the value in a `::std::uint32_t` and divide it by `86400000.0` (aka, the number of microseconds in a day) whenever you need it as a scaled number like you were talking about. Of course, with a `::std::uint32_t` you could only store a time duration of about 45 days maximum. So, if it gets bigger than that, and you still want all the microseconds of precision, store it as a `::std::uint64_t`.

Essentially, you'd be treating your number as the numerator of a fraction who's denominator is implicitly `86400000`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest is to just store the number of microseconds in a `uint64_t`. This will allow you to store over 200,000,000 days so is plenty for your needs and has no rounding errors.

Another solution would be to just use [`std::chrono::microseconds`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) (which is probably just a `int64_t` internally) which then allows you to convert to other duration units. To get back to your floating point days for printing you can do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
  typedef std::chrono::duration< double, std::ratio<86400> > float_days;
  auto time = 12345678us;
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast< float_days >( time ).count() << " days\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, using one of the `::std::chrono` types is probably better than using a bare `::std::uint64_t`. I haven't yet found a good, cohesive description of that part of the standard library, and all the interlocking pieces are kind of confusing without an overarching explanation to tie them together.

Answer (score 0):

As said in other places, it depends. If you need precision higher than `double` but still a fixed one you may go with custom floating point type implementation. If you need unlimited precision you might go for different way of storing this number. For example using two big integers which represent it as common fraction.